# Exclude filter on front page

Tags: loop, filters, excerpt, read-more

I am using this code in `functions.php` to append a button for link to a post.

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
 global $post;
 return '<a class="excerpt-readmore" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

In `front-page.php` I have `get_template_part('content-ctp');` and in that file I have

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'radovi'
    );
$ctp = new WP_Query($args);
...
the_excerpt();
```

Is there a way to not have the read-more button only for this specific loop? 
I don't think I can check with `if(!is_front_page())` on filter since I also have 2 more loops on front page where I need that button. 
Any suggestions on how to do it properly the Wordpress way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just remove the filter before calling `the_excerpt` and then add it back afterwards...

```
remove_filter('excerpt_more','new_excerpt_more');
the_excerpt();
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: LOL nice trick, ty :)